# sonar C# ecosystem: how to configure IT test coverage

Tags: c#, plugins, integration-testing, sonarqube

We have a .NET C# solution with some first integrationtests, but no unit tests. How do I have to configure the sonar-project.properties to get test execution and code coverage to work?
When using:

```
sonar.dotnet.visualstudio.testProjectPattern=*.Tests;*.Test
sonar.dotnet.visualstudio.itProjectPattern=*.IntegrationTest
sonar.opencover.installDirectory=C:/Program Files/OpenCover
sonar.gallio.coverage.tool=OpenCover
sonar.gallio.runner=IsolatedProcess
sonar.gallio.it.mode=active
```

sonar says:

```
14:42:55.813 INFO  p.d.a.m.ModelFactory - The project 'foo.IntegrationTest' has been  qualified as a test project.
14:42:55.844 INFO  p.d.a.m.ModelFactory - The project 'bar.IntegrationTest' has been qualified as a test project.
...
Gallio won't execute as there are no test projects
```

When changing the test Patterns:

```
sonar.dotnet.visualstudio.testProjectPattern=*.IntegrationTest
#sonar.dotnet.visualstudio.itProjectPattern=*.IntegrationTest
```

gallio executes the integration tests as "unit tests" and code coverage works. Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this for code coverage generation.
For example project is Test/Test.csproj

```
cd ./Test
nuget install Microsoft.CodeCoverage -OutputDirectory ./packages
```

in ./packages in nested directories will be CodeCoverage.exe

```
dotnet test --no-build logger trx --collect "CodeCoverage" /p:Debug=full -- DataCollectionRunSettings.DataCollectors.DataCollector.Configuration.CoverageFileName="test.coverage"
```

In TestResults in nested directories there will be test.coverage file.
Transform it to coveragexml

```
CodeCoverage.exe analyze /output:test.coveragexml test.coverage
```

Then use it in sonarscanner

```
./SonarScannerMsbuild.exe /d:"sonar.cs.vstest.reportsPaths=./**/*.trx" /d:"sonar.cs.vscoveragexml.reportsPaths=./**/*coveragexml"
```